# Laravel: Storage::url() returning wrong bucket

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am uploading a file to S3 and specifying a bucket.  When I check my S3 dashboard, it's in the right place and right bucket (`s3-legacy-users`).  But when I go to retrieve the URL, the bucket is not `s3-legacy-users` but a different bucket.  Is there a way to specify the bucket when using `Storage::url()` ?

```
    $file = $request->file('file');

    $fileName = $file->hashName();
    $image = Image::make($file->getRealPath());

    $newPath = '/'.shop_id().'/'.$imageType.'-'.$fileName;

    $fileUpload = Storage::disk('s3-legacy-users')->put($newPath, $image->stream()->__toString());
    $filePath = Storage::url($newPath);

    dd($filePath);
```

Comment: `$filePath = Storage::disk('s3-legacy-users')->url($newPath);` You need to specify your disk if you have several storage drivers

Comment: You welcome, I added the answer accordingly, please accept it so it can help others as well 

Comment: @ChristopheHubert yep, just did! thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify your disk if you have several storage drivers:

```
$filePath = Storage::disk('s3-legacy-users')->url($newPath);
```